# I get map object null on onStart() method

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, mapbox, android-lifecycle

I'm trying to addMarker when I open my fragment so in onMap Ready function I assigned my map and I'm calling map onStart() method but I get null

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
    map = mapboxMap;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mapView.onStart();
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null) {
        System.out.println("MY PATROL => "+args);
        mapboxAddMarker(args.getString("QRResult"));
    }
}

public void mapboxAddMarker(String coords){
    String[] coordArr =coords.split(" ");

    LatLng coord = new LatLng();
    coord.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(coordArr[0]));
    coord.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(coordArr[1]));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(coord));
}
```

Also, I know addMarker is deprecated but it's an example I'll fix it.

Lastly My Error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.rtets, PID: 10727
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.Marker com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.addMarker(com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.rtets.ui.fragments.MyPatrolFragment.mapboxAddMarker(MyPatrolFragment.java:83)
        at com.example.rtets.ui.fragments.MyPatrolFragment.onViewCreated(MyPatrolFragment.java:96)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2987)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Comment: have you debugged your code? are you sure onMapReady is being called?

Comment: yes I have it's not even calling

Comment: so there is your issue. you'll need to instantiate map in onStart

Comment: I can not instantiate map in onStart because I need MapboxMap object  but I can get this object only in onMapReady function I searched for this error they say you forget to call getMapAsync but I didn't  In onCreateView  I called it and It works

Comment: if `onMapReady` isn't called at all then you should post snippet responsible for initializing map (`onCreate`?)

Comment: @snachmsm I didn't get your solution  but the problem is onMapReady is not calling even I called the getMapAsync method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I solved my problem  I implemented my fragment `OnMapReadyCallback`

and overridden it but I think in the fragment that does not work so I deleted the `OnMapReadyCallback` and I wrote `OnMapReadyCallback` in `getMapAsync` method

```
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
            System.out.println("MAP IS OKAY");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you simply can't be shure that `onMapReady` will be called before `Activity`s lifecycle callback will be called (like `onStart` or `onResume`). Map initialization is async operation, thus you have to pass callback for getting information when it is ready (just like method says). you should init your markers in `onMapReady`

Comment: Maybe I want to add marker after 10 secounds of onMapReady or something like that is there any ways to addMarker or SetStyle out of onMapReady

Comment: you can add at any time, also in `onStart`, there is a chance that on some fast devices map will load (`onMapReady` called) before `onStart` and your current code will work. BUT you must be always aware that `map` reference may be `null` as map may be initializing for split of second, few seconds, or even never initialize. so add persistent markers (from bundle) just after proper initialization (`onMapReady` call) and after that you may work with `map` object at any time (as long as `Activity`/`Fragment` is running)

Comment: yeah true words but even if check null control how can I handle the null map situation as a conclusion my map is null and the things that I want to do with map can not be done

Comment: well, just don't do "map stuff", instead show some splash informing user that map can't be loaded. you can introduce own timer starting in `onCreate` and firing e.g. 5 secs later checking that map is initialized properly. if not make some UI fallback with proper info, if yes enable map-related features/GUI. markers should be loaded as soon as map loads, so in `onMapReady`